# (PdfSharp) How do I use pdfsharp to change the page size of an existing pdf file?

Tags: pdf, pdfsharp

I have a pdf file of the Legal page size, how do I change it to Letter size using PdfSharp?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 3):

PDFsharp includes a "Two Pages on One" sample. I'd use this as a starter; it draws two portrait pages on one landscape page. It can easily be changed to copy one portrait page onto a new portrait page.
Letter is larger than legal. So you must decide how to handle that:

- scale the height to fit while maintaining the width
- shrink height and width proportionally to keep the aspect ratio
- keep page size truncating at the bottom keep page size
- truncating at top and bottom (same or different stretches)

The first two options will work with any document, the final two could be appropriate if you know the documents and know you don't lose important information.